# how to fix failed loading controller in controller manager

Tags: ros-control, ros-humble, controller-manager

I'm trying to use spawner for the custom controller to use different controllers like the joint trajectory controller and the forward command controller in a launch file.

***This is controller.yaml file:***

```yaml
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10

    arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    # gripper_controller:
    #   type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    gripper_controller:
      type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      -joint_1
      -joint_2
      -joint_3
    
    command_interfaces:
      -position
      
    state_interfaces:
      -position
    
    open_loop_control: true
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true

gripper_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      -joint_4
    
    interface_name: position
    # command_interfaces:
    #   -position
    # state_interfaces:
    #   -position

    # open_loop_control: true
    # allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
```

***This is my launch file:***

```python
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

def generate_launch_description():
    
    robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(['xacro ', os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("robot_description"),"urdf","robot_des.urdf.xacro")]),
                                       value_type=str)
 
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}]
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_node = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster', "--controller-manager","/controller_manager"]
    )
    
    arm_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['arm_controller', "--controller-manager","/controller_manager"]
    )
    
    gripper_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['gripper_controller', "--controller-manager","/controller_manager"]
    )
    

 
    return LaunchDescription([
        
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_broadcaster_node,
        arm_controller_spawner,
        gripper_controller_spawner

    ])
```

**This is my terminal output when I'm trying to launch the controller using above launch file**

```log
ubuntu@instance-20230806-0136:~/ros2motion$ ros2 launch arm_robot_control controller.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2023-08-27-15-50-24-736711-instance-20230806-0136-257488
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [257498]
[INFO] [spawner-2]: process started with pid [257500]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [257502]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [257505]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.672522283] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.675259673] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_plate
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.675883014] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment claw_support
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.687073843] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forward_drive_arm
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.687625598] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_left
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.688204315] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_right
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.694970715] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment horizontal_arm
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1693151425.695374865] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[spawner-2] [INFO] [1693151427.513446324] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-4] [FATAL] [1693151427.606168788] [spawner_gripper_controller]: Failed loading controller gripper_controller
[spawner-3] [FATAL] [1693151427.724714084] [spawner_arm_controller]: Failed loading controller arm_controller
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 257505, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner gripper_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 257502, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner arm_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
[spawner-2] [INFO] [1693151428.065387725] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 257500]
```

***URDF control file***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="arm_robot">

    <xacro:property name="PI" value="3.14159"/>

    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <joint name="joint_1">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <params name="min">-${PI/2}</params>
            <params name="mav">${PI/2}</params>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_2">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <params name="min">-${PI/2}</params>
            <params name="mav">${PI/2}</params>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_3">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <params name="min">-${PI/2}</params>
            <params name="mav">${PI/2}</params>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        
        </joint>

        <joint name="joint_4">
            <command_interface name="position">
                <params name="min">-${PI/2}</params>
                <params name="mav">0.0</params>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        
        </joint>
        <joint name="joint_5">
            <param name="mimic">joint_4</param>
            <param name="multiplier">-1</param>
            <command_interface name="position">
                <params name="min">0.0</params>
                <params name="mav">${PI/2}</params>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>

</robot>
```

***Gazebo URDF file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
            <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
            <parameters>$(find arm_robot_control)/config/arm_robot_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>
```

Can someone please help me fix the problem fail to the load controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your URDF it is hard to answer. What type of hardware_component are you using? Simulation or custom plugin? If you don't have one: Have a look at the [demos](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html) how to setup your ros2_control framework.

(Edit) Summary:
Have a look in the output of the controller_manager (where you launched gazebo.launch.py):

```
[gzserver-1] Exception thrown during init stage with message: parameter 'joints' has invalid type: expected [string_array] got [string]
```

This comes from a wrong syntax in your yaml, you have to add a space between the dashes and strings, e.g. `- joint_1` instead of `-joint_1` –

Comment: Thanks, Christoph, I have updated the URDF in question. I'm waiting for a response.

Comment: This is still not your full URDF, but it seems that you haven't loaded the gazebo plugin properly. See [this](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_9/doc/userdoc.html) example for a template.
Especially the part with `<plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">` is missing.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, here is the remaining URDF file ````<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
            <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
            <parameters>$(find arm_robot_control)/config/arm_robot_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>``` here is so conjugated, I will update in the question.

Comment: I still can't try to get that running without the robot description URDF. 
From your console output it is clear that the gazebo_ros2_control isn't loaded correctly. 
Try to activate debug output, and also have a look into  `~/.gazebo/server-xx/default.log` if there is any hint why it didn't load.

Comment: btw: You have misspelled the `max`parameter in the other URDF, but that makes the plugin not crashing.

Comment: Hi Christoph You can clone or download complete branch from repo here https://github.com/AdithyaDamarla/ROS2_Motion_Planning.git please let me know and thanks

Comment: Have a look in the output of the controller_manager (where you launched gazebo.launch.py): `[gzserver-1] Exception thrown during init stage with message: parameter 'joints' has invalid type: expected [string_array] got [string]`

Comment: This comes from a wrong syntax in your yaml, you have to add a space between the dashes and strings, e.g. 
`- joint_1`  instead of `-joint_1`

Comment: Thanks alot Christoph, you solved my problem. Now,  it is working.

Comment: no problem :) please mark the question as solved by means of the check mark next to the answer.